Blender video sequencer rendering image but not ffmpeg
I've seen similar threads to this but the only solution I've seen to this specific problem is unchecking the compositor box under output, however I've done that and had no change in the result. I've never encountered this before and honestly can't think of anything I'd have done to trigger this... it just pulls up a blank render result every time I render animation and nothing gets saved to the file destination.
Edit: just realised Blender doesn't render ffmpeg from the 3d viewport either, even after resetting to factory settings, really confused.



You have disabled Saving > File Extensions. Your screenshot does not show your full Output path, but if you do not have a file name with the *.mp4 extension there, Blender cannot save the file. You might not have noticed, but after trying to start rendering, there should appear a message at the bottom for a moment which says "Could not open file for writing".

Message in bottom status bar:


Oof. Sounds like a thing that should be changed on Blender's side... I'll post that on RCS, perhaps even propose a patch.

@Lauloque It is only affecting rendering directly to video, not image sequences. It is nothing new, has been like that for ages.

So it was a combination of having file extensions turned off + what I didn't include in my screenshot, the X resolution of the render was an odd number... which Blender didn't like.
